# Propensity score matching by gender in stata

Tags: stata, matching, propensity-scores, regression-strategies

Hello Stack Community!

I'm trying to do a matching in Stata. I need to do a propensity score matching between a single individuals dataset (men and women) to a couple dataset. What I like to do is to match (not merge since they are not the same individuals) a dataset containing only single women and men observations to a couple dataset (containing men a women observations for couples). The single dataset contains information not available in the couple dataset, therefore my interest on the matching.

After a lot of research (I'm not familiar with matching), I did the following: I treated the single dataset as the one not getting the 'treatement' and created a variable to indicate so (which I called 'z'). Then I merged the couples dataset to the singles dataset, the former one was considered as the individuals that received the treatment.

Finally I matched by gender using the psmatched2 command by individual caractheristics. The problem is the option 'if' is not allowed, so I cannot match by gender specifically and since this is the key point of my matching (I need a gender specific matching) I wonder how can I do it.

My second problem is that I am not sure whether I should consider the couple dataset as those being 'treated', since the missing data that I need is in the singles dataset shouldn't I use it as the 'treated' group? My variable out are the missing variables that I need from the singles dataset to the couples dataset.

Here is my code, hope you can help me! Thanks a lot!

```
use "F:\SINGLES.DTA", clear
gen z=0
sort id
save "F:\SINGLES.DTA", replace

use "F:\COUPLES.DTA", clear
gen z=1
sort id
merge id using "F:\SINGLES.DTA"
psmatch2 z age education urban prop l_ingtotpc, out(wfood_f whogar_f wtransporte_f wclothing_f wpc_f wsalud_f wleisure_f weduc_f) if female==1
```

Comment: There is a vote to close this question as off-topic but I voted against this. Even though it appears to be mainly concerned with Stata at first sight a good answer to this question will also provide a thorough theoretical explanation as to why this split-sample approach would be appropriate for propensity score matching as proposed by the OP.

Comment: As it stands this question is focused on Stata code. I am happy to believe that there's a relevant statistical question buried inside. While it's in limbo, I note that the claim that `psmatch2` (above misnamed `psmatched2`) does not allow an `if` qualifier (above misnamed an option) is incorrect. See the help file.

Comment: The problem with the last code line above is that `if` is specified with the options: it should be specified before.